# Minimalist Facebook chat client for Android

Tags: android, chat, facebook

Ever since chat stopped working on Facebook's website, I have been looking for an alternative to the bloaty spyware-laden Messenger app. There are many alternatives, many of which even share the same name -- very confusing.

Which one would you recommend?

Ideal criteria:

- Part of a multiprotocol app.
- Supports OTR, with ability to import private keys.
- Saves chat history.
- No unreasonable permissions granted! No location, local phone contacts, local files, SMS or phone access---nothing but network access, which is all it needs.
- Supports user searching.
- No new accounts need to be made. I want it to log onto Facebook directly, using the same protocol Messenger uses.

Video and audio not necessary.

Need not be free.

Comment: Did you try [Disa](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.disa&hl=en) ?

Comment: I'm trying out Disa now. So far, so good. You should add that recommendation as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disa](http://www.disa.im/)  is my recommendation.It is a platform for unified messaging you can connect several IM into this open source program.Disa has everything that a traditional IM can offer.

[image]

You can get it from [Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.disa&hl=en)

Comment: Yeah, Disa is pretty good. It still lacks Hangouts and generic XMPP, which was surprising, but still, pretty good. It'll do for now. Thanks!

Comment: Could you briefly elaborate whether and how Disa is less "bloaty" and "spyware-laden", as the OP says, than the original FB messenging app,  please?